# How to select a value from DropDown list using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have the following drop down list that I want to select the value "Previous Year" from:

[image: Html_section]

(I've already selected the value manually)

The problem is two fold, I'm having a hard time "finding" or locating this drop down list with my code, and the number in the "id" changes page to page, so I can't just locate it by its "id". I'm trying to use the following Python 3 code:

```
select = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "dropdown-intervaltype")]')
select.click()
# then click the "Previous Year" text
```

and I also tried:

```
select = Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "dropdown-intervaltype")]'))
select.select_by_value("Previous Year")
```

Now this site is a private site for work, so I can't grant access, but I'm hoping someone can point out what else I can try to locate this element and select the proper drop down value? I've tried locating this field by "css" and "xpath", no luck.

```
xpath = //*[@id="dropdown-intervaltype31442"]
css_selector = #dropdown-intervaltype31442
full_xpath = /html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/select
```

Any ideas to test would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<select>` element is a dynamic element. So to select the `<option>` with text as **Previous Year** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id^='dropdown-intervaltype'][name^='deviceServicesModel']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('Previous Year')
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[starts-with(@id, 'dropdown-intervaltype')][starts-with(@name,'deviceServicesModel')]"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('Previous Year')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)

Comment: Perfect! Used the CSS selector method and worked. THANK YOU!

Comment: @MattWilson There was minor bug in the _xpath_ which I have corrected now and should work as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath :

new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[starts-with(@id, 'dropdown-intervaltype')][starts-with(@name,'deviceServicesModel')]"))).selectByVisibleText("Privious Year");

You can also use id:

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownintervaltype"))).selectByVisibleText("Argentina");

You check Your xpath And take correct xpath. I hope this answer is useful for you.