# Python Selenium - Drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

EDIT : SOLVED !

I just started using selenium and I can't seem to figure out how to
choose from the drop down menu. I'm trying to choose the ***Metered Volumes (All)*** option under the ***SelectReport*** but it's giving me an error saying that the ***SelectReport*** element does not exist.

Here's the HTML of the [site](http://ets.aeso.ca/ets_web/docroot/Market/Reports/HistoricalReportsStart.html):

```html
<select name="SelectReport" size="1" onchange="populateReportType(document.reportForm, getCurrReportObj())">
              <option selected="" value="NO LINK">
                Select a Report
              </option>
              <option value="NO LINK">
              </option>
            <option value="NO LINK">SETTLEMENT</option>
            <option value="Market/Reports/PublicSummaryAllReportServlet">--- Metered Volumes (All)</option>
            <option value="Market/Reports/DdsPaymentSummaryReportServlet">--- DDS Payment Summary</option>
            <option value="Market/Reports/DdsChargeSummaryReportServlet">--- DDS 
......
            </select>
```

And here's what I tried so far:

```
select = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_name("SelectReport"))
select.select_by_value("Market/Reports/PublicSummaryAllReportServlet")
```

It would be really helpful if someone can help. I've been stuck with this issue for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 1):

To select the `<option>` with text as **Metered Volumes (All)** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `select_by_visible_text()`:

  ```
  # presuming the actual option text is "Metered Volumes (All)"
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[name='SelectReport']")))).select_by_visible_text("Metered Volumes (All)")
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `select_by_value()`:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='SelectReport']")))).select_by_value("Market/Reports/PublicSummaryAllReportServlet")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)