# Django Selenium test onclick not calling function

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, onclick, html-select, webdriverwait

In a Selenium test of my homepage I ran into the following problem:

I have a number of buttons on the page. When clicking one of them a selections list is populated with a number of options via a javascript function. After clicking one of the buttons the selection list can look like this:

```
<select id="selectionList" name="List1" size="10" style="width:100%;">
<option style="color:#0275d8">Item Type 1</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_1">Item 1</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_2">Item 2</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_3">Item 3</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_4">Item 4</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_5">Item 5</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_6">Item 6</option>
<option style="color:#0275d8">Item Type 2</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_7">Item 7</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_8">Item 8</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_9">Item 9</option>
<option onclick="onSelection()" id="Item_10">Item 10</option>
</select>
```

In my test I used the following to click on one of the items.

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Item_1']"))).click()
```

I do see that item 1 gets highlighted but the onSelection() function is not called.

I also tried this

```
time.sleep(10)
self.browser.find_element_by_id("Item_1").click()
```

Again item 1 gets highlighted but the function onSelection() is not called.

Any idea of how to solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to be a known problem

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2556

the issue is marked closed but seemingly only because the original reporter abandoned the issue and/or because it is an imported bug reported from an older issue tracker.

there is one reported workaround in the discussion

```
driver.action.click_and_hold(element).perform
sleep(1)
driver.action.release.perform
```

i think the code is informal because AFAIK there is no `driver.action`. instead you have to do `actions = ActionChains(driver)`.

see here for more information: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-actionchains-class-in-selenium-with-python

Comment: Thanks for directing me towards ActionChains. I used following solution: ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Item_1")))).click().perform() It works nicely

Answer (score 0):

The element is a [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element so you need to use the `Select()` class.

To select the `<option>` with text as **Item 1** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#selectionList[name='List1']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('Item 1')
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='selectionList' and @name='List1']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text('Item 1')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)

Comment: This import is also needed: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
Your suggestion does not solve the issue. Again the item is selected but the function is not called. I managed to solve the issue using ActionChains, see above.

Comment: @Tola Added the import