# Selecting options using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, html-select, webdriverwait, select-options

I know there were several examples with selenium option-selecting. Nevertheless, I still cannot select one in one specific website.
https://www.gks.ru/dbscripts/munst/munst20/DBInet.cgi
I want to  choose Excel option in the top-left Select.
The HTML is n attachment

[image]

I tried approaching the bar this way

```el
for option in el.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'option'):
    print(option.text)
    if option.text == 'CSV':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

I also used find_elements by class and css_selector

Then I used

```
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'Select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Excel')
```

It could not locate the element either

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

To select the [select-options](/questions/tagged/select-options) with text as ***CSV*** from the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.Select[name='Format']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text("CSV")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='Select' and @name='Format']"))))
  select.select_by_visible_text("CSV")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)

Comment: Just adding a point here. It is a drop-down element right so I beleive using `presenceOfElement` works instead of `elementToBeClickable` or `visibilityOfElement`?

Comment: Going by the best practices you are totally correct. I'm just over cautious :/