# Python Selenium How to Select from Dropdown?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was testing my code over: https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

I wrote the following code in Python3 which finds all drop-downs in a given webpage and selects the last option for each drop-down:

```
dropdowns = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@class="ui dropdown"]')
print(str(len(form_dropdowns)))
for drop_down in form_dropdowns:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", drop_down)
    options = drop_down.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='option')
    print(str(len(options)))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", options[len(options) - 1])
time.sleep(100)
```

I see the following printed on screen:

```
2
3
3
```

Which means 2 drop-downs were found, both with 3 options to select from.

BUT I don't see any value being changed in the UI, why is that?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are doing through `print(str(len(form_dropdowns)))` and `for drop_down in form_dropdowns` where as you got `dropdowns = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//select[@class="ui dropdown"]')`

Comment: The elements are not visible also it seems there is a div that actually does the genders.

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems OP's approach to select the last option using the following line of code is working,

```
 driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", options[len(options) - 1])
```

I'm totally against the idea of **selecting the last option**.

Ideally to interact with any [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element we must be using the *`Select()`* class and use either among the *option index*, *option value* or *option text* to choose the desired *`<option>`*.

As an example,

- Using *`select_by_value()`*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_select_element")))).select_by_value("value")
  ```
- Using *`select_by_visible_text()`*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath_select_element")))).select_by_visible_text("text")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selecting options using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, for some reason I got blocked and can't test that website I will test and accept very soon. Just a side note, isn't really there an option to select last one? I don't know the name as I'm writing general purpose code that is supposed to work on almost all scenarios.

Comment: Update: It's not working.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I won't accept as my problem is still unresolved.

Comment: I'm still not sure with which select element(s) you are trying to interact. However its a generic solution. You need to replace _`xpath_select_element`_ with a realtime xpath.