# Selenium Select to return a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In python we have:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('fruits01'))
```

But what if I want to have a list of all select tags and not just the first one?

I tried:

```
select = Select(driver.find_elements_by_id('fruits01'))
```

But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Selenium Python API Docs of [`Select()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select):

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select(webelement)
    A check is made that the given element is, indeed, a SELECT tag. If it is not, then an UnexpectedTagNameException is thrown.
```

So *`Select()`* takes a ***webelement*** as an argument and you won't be able to pass ***webelements***.

Moreover, each webelement is unique within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). So it's highly unlikely multiple elements would be identified using the same value of `id` attribute i.e. *`fruits01`*.

---

### This usecase

However, considering the usecase as a valid usecase the simplest approach would be similar to *`@Arundeep Chohan`*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622885/7429447) but ideally inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) as follows:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "fruits01")))
for element in elements:
    select = Select(element)
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Can you kindly check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622370/python-selenium-how-to-select-from-dropdown

Comment: @Algo Did you get a chance to look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71623422/7429447) over there?

Answer (score 1):

```
elems=driver.find_elements_by_id('fruits01')
for elem in elems:
   select=Select(elem)
```

Why not just use a list to loop them ? I don't think you can do it the way you want to.