# Selenium: Select by number within span element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

All avaible sizes had same class but I need to select by numbers in span.
I tried by doing this, but select function dont work with span element.

Code trials:

```
SIZECHOOSE=Select(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"RYghuO._7Cm1F9.dgII7d.pVrzNP"))
SIZECHOOSE.select_by_visible_text("41")
```

Snapshot of HTML:

[image: Code of website Zalando]

Comment: Do you need every element with the number 41? You can scrap all of them, and then filter... Just an idea

Comment: @interferemadly I need it to pick a random number from the numbers I specify in advance and to filter unavailable and replace with available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element is not a [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element so you won't be able to use the [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) class.

To click on a any specific number you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and `normalize-space()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[normalize-space()='42']").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., '42')]").click()
  ```

Comment: I know that's why I'm asking how to do with span class.

Comment: Thanks, using xpath and normalize-space() works.