# How to select calender month using Selenium Select method using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to select a month from the calender using Select method of selenium in python.
URL of site is: https://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/matchups/ .
I am getting timeout error and the driver is unable to find the select element of calender. Code is as follows:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
click_calender=wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'datepicker'))
        )
click_calender.click()
select_month = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pika-title-yj"]/div[1]/select'))))
select_month.select_by_visible_text("June")
```

I am getting a timeout error on Select method as this:

```
select_month = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pika-title-yj"]/div[1]/select'))))

File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00636463+2188387]
        Ordinal0 [0x005CE461+1762401]
        Ordinal0 [0x004E3D78+802168]
        Ordinal0 [0x00511880+989312]
        Ordinal0 [0x00511B1B+989979]
        Ordinal0 [0x0053E912+1173778]
        Ordinal0 [0x0052C824+1099812]
        Ordinal0 [0x0053CC22+1166370]
        Ordinal0 [0x0052C5F6+1099254]
        Ordinal0 [0x00506BE0+945120]
        Ordinal0 [0x00507AD6+948950]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008D71F2+2712546]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008C886D+2652765]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006C002A+520730]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x006BEE06+516086]
        Ordinal0 [0x005D468B+1787531]
        Ordinal0 [0x005D8E88+1805960]
        Ordinal0 [0x005D8F75+1806197]
        Ordinal0 [0x005E1DF1+1842673]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x774CFA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779E7A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x779E7A6E+238]
```

I have tried to click the month element but I am unable to do so as well. Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: Where did you got `//*[@id="pika-title-yj"]/div[1]/select` within the HTML? Or `//*[@id="pika-title-yj"]` per se?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates of the calendar are *`<button>`* tags

[image: vegasinsider]

So you can't use [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) class.

---

### Solution

To chose a date e.g. *`July 3rd, 2022`* instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*css_selector*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578370/7429447) based [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.vegasinsider.com/mlb/matchups/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#datepicker"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-pika-year='2022'][data-pika-month='6'][data-pika-day='3']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```