# Non-Select Drop-down list selection using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to print the options and select "Manhattan" from the "city" dropdown search box on this website: https://upxland.me/properties/ . But every time I run it, the program end without printing anything. In addition, could anyone show me how to type part of a city's name (like "Manha") and then select  from the dropdown list?

My code is shown below. Could anyone help?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://upxland.me/properties/")
try:
    city = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'input-74')))

    # city.send_keys("o")
    # city.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    city_selection = Select(city)
    # print the number of option
    print(len(city_selection.options))

    # print all options
    for option in city_selection.options:
        print(option.text)

    # select by index
    city_selection.select_by_index(3)
    time.sleep(3)
    # select by value
    # city_selection.select_by_value()

except:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element isn't within any [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag, but they are within `<div>` tag.

[image: upxland]

So you won't be able to use [**Select()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) class.

---

### Solution

To print the option texts you can use [*List Comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69947765/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://upxland.me/properties/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accept all']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='City']//following-sibling::input[1]"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v-menu__content theme--dark menuable__content__active v-autocomplete__content']//div[@role='option']//div[@class='v-list-item__title']")))])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  ['Los Angeles', 'San Francisco', 'Manhattan', 'Queens', 'Fresno', 'Brooklyn', 'Oakland', 'Staten Island', 'Bakersfield', 'Chicago', 'Cleveland', 'Santa Clara', 'Rutherford', 'Kansas City', 'New Orleans', 'Nashville', 'Bronx', 'Detroit', 'Las Vegas']
  ```

To select **Manhattan**:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='v-menu__content theme--dark menuable__content__active v-autocomplete__content']//div[@role='option']//div[@class='v-list-item__title' and text()='Manhattan']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks! I inspected the "City" dropdown and copied Xpath '/*[@id="list-74"]'. Why this path didn't work while your path "//label[text()='City']//following-sibling::input[1]" worked? And may I ask what's the difference between EC. presence_of_element_located and EC. element_to_be_clickable?

Comment: @Chloe You shouldn't trust `74` from `/*[@id="list-74"]`, dynamically generated number and is bound to change sooner or later

Answer (score 0):

You need to click and enter some text in the input box for city.
Then add 1 sec wait. Then use the options xpath to get a list of elements.

Get text for each element by Iterating through the list till you get the required city and then click on it.

The xpath for the select element is -

```
//input[@placeholder="City"]
```

The xpath for the options for select element is -

```
//div[contains(@class,'content__active v-autocomplete__content')]//div[@class='v-list-item__title']
```