# Selenium Select not working on dropdown element

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

So I am trying to run the following code to select an option from a drop-down toolbar:

```
## Drop-down menu
time.sleep(5) # wait for element to load in page otherwise selenium won't be able to find it
element_dropdown = driver.find_element("id","conference-dropdowns")
element_dropdown.click()

# Select visible text
time.sleep(5)
select = Select(element_dropdown)
select.select_by_visible_text("Bulk Upload")
```

But then I get the following error:

```
UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <label>
```

How do I resolve this issue? Why am I getting this error? See structure below. Thanks so much in advance.
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Testing, or you want to scrape the data? If scraping, post the full url.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 I'm trying to create a program that will login to a site, navigate through a few toolbars and upload a CSV file after clicking "Bulk Upload".

Comment: If your end goal is to upload a file, you can achieve this with requests - you can login, then upload that file.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire_333 Oh cool! Could you send some resources on how to achieve this? I'm very new to Selenium, requests, etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892729/how-to-log-in-to-a-website-using-pythons-requests-module and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/how-to-upload-file-with-python-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element isn't within any [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag, but they are within `<label>` tag.

[image: Bulk Upload]

So you won't be able to use [**Select()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) class.

---

### Solution

The click element with text as **Bulk Upload** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='dropdown-submenu']//label[@class='submenu' and contains(., 'Bulk Upload')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The Exception says everything: you can use [`Select`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) class only with [`<select>` object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp).
Simply try to

- `click()` on button to expand drop-down menu
- [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) for required option to be clickable
- `click()` on option