# How to select dropdown in the dynamic table Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have HTML tables like

```
<table id='table1'>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Food</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Burger</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" id="xx2" onchange="count(this)">
                <option value="1">Burger</option>
                <option value="2">spaghetti</option>
                <option value="3">Kebab</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'>Drink</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Burger</td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" id="kj2" onchange="count(this)">
                <option value="1">Coffe</option>
                <option value="2">Tea</option>
                <option value="3">Milk</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2'> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> .......... </td>
        <td>
            <select class="form-control input-sm" id="jj" onchange="count(this)">
                <option value="1"> ... </option>
                <option value="2"> ..... </option>
                <option value="3"> .... </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>       
</tbody>
```

In selenium web driver, how to select first value at dropdownlist in the dynamic table (total rows is varry and there is colspan)

I have get table, and I want to get all and fill dropdownlist in the table

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table1"]/tbody')))    
table = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table1"]/tbody')
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all vary data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
  
main_site = requests.get("http://yourhtmlfile.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_site.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(attrs={'id':'table1'})
select = table.find(attrs={'id':'xx2'})
res = []
for option in select.find_all('option'):
    res.append(option["value"])
```

all option data is stored into res list

```
selectedDropDownList = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "xx2"))
selectedDropDownList.select_by_visible_text(res[0])
```

so, you can repeat this method to fullfill all dropdownlist

Comment: how to get element ID in each dropdown in the table? because element ID is vary

Comment: you can use beautifulSoup to do that,i have edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below XPath:

To select the first dropdown:

```
dropdown_1 = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//*[@id='table1']//select[@class='form-control input-sm'])[1]"))
```

To select the second or third dropdown you can change the index in the XPath:

```
(.//*[@id='table1']//select[@class='form-control input-sm'])[2]
```

or

```
(.//*[@id='table1']//select[@class='form-control input-sm'])[3]
```

To select the first option from the dropdown:

```
dropdown_1.select_by_value(1)
```

or

```
dropdown_1.select_by_index(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your html structure, you can use item reference like `food` or `drink` and then target following `select` element.

Use following `xpath` to identify each dropdown element.

**dropdwon 1:** `"//td[text()='Food']/following::select[1]"`

**dropdwon 2:** `"//td[text()='Drink']/following::select[1]"`

Use selenium `select` class to select the drop down values.
To handle dynamic element use `WebDriverWait()` and want for element clickable.

```
selectFood=Select(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//td[text()='Food']/following::select[1]"))))

selectFood.select_by_value(1)

selectDrink=Select(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//td[text()='Drink']/following::select[1]"))))

selectDrink.select_by_value(1)
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

Answer (score 0):

There are total three (3) [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) elements within the HTML provided and to select an option you have to use the [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) class and inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
# using select_by_visible_text() to select spaghetti
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='xx2']")))).select_by_visible_text("spaghetti")

# using select_by_index() to select Tea
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='kj2']")))).select_by_index(2)

# using select_by_value() to select the second option from the third dropdown
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='jj']")))).select_by_value('2')
```