# Selenium Driver unable to locate an element within a scroll bar list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, scrollbar

I am web scraping a URL https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/datarequest/D149.

Within that page I am clicking on http://wonder.cdc.gov/natality-expanded-current.html and then I am clicking on I Agree button.
In Section 10 there is a scroll bar list of Year, for which I am using below code

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="SD149.V20"]//option[@value="2016"]'))).click()
```

However its not able to select the element. Please help on same.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No error. But it is not selecting the year which I am passing.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Put a break point before clicking on `2016` dropdown and notice its not highlighted. After clicking the dropdown value you can notice that the `2016` gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working just fine, i.e. it is actually selecting value `2016` from dropdown. However what I notice when you click on `2016` is, it selects `2016` and `2021` both(see below).

[image]

So, to deselect `2021` and keep only `2016` selected, use the below code:

```
# use below line to deselect 2021
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="SD149.V20"]//option[@value="2021"]'))).click()
# use below line to select 2016
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//select[@id="SD149.V20"]//option[@value="2016"]'))).click()
```

Result after adding the above code:

[image]

**FYI : Another way to select the dropdown values in Selenium:**

You can use selenium's `Select` class to handle dropdowns, see the code below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, "SD149.V20"))
select.select_by_value("2016")
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element:

```
<option value="2016">&nbsp;2016&nbsp;</option>
```

is an `<option>` tag within it's parent `<select>` tag.

---

### This usecase

Ideally to select an `<option>` from an [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) you need to use the [`Select()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) method inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://wonder.cdc.gov/controller/datarequest/D149")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.w-sys-message p a[href*='natality']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='action-I Agree']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='hd' and contains(., 'Select delivery characteristics')]"))))
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id='SD149.V20']")))).deselect_all()
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id='SD149.V20']")))).select_by_value("2016")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Select]

**Note**: The option with text ***2016*** does get selected but you need to scroll a bit up to verify it manually.