# Python Selenium NoSuchElementException although the element is there

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nosuchelementexception, findelement

i was trying to build a webscraper but i came to the point where i try to select a select-element() but Selenium cant find the object and throws the Exception.

I used find_element with the correct XPATH (100% sure), but it just doesnt work. I tried to find it by its name but i think the XPATH is the only thing that'll work in my case.

**Complete code. The problem is the last selection**

```
import data
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(data.login_site)

username_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_username")
username_input.send_keys(username)
password_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "_password")
password_input.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary']")
login_button.click()

plaene_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/iserv/plan/overview']")
plaene_button.click()

plaene_show = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/iserv/plan/show/Plan%20Schueler']")
plaene_show.click()

time.sleep(4)
drpdClass = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/form/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/nobr/select"))

time.sleep(10)
```

[Picture of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xLUg.png)

Comment: Please just put the code into the question as text.

Comment: Try the class name. Include your code and also the website link

Comment: it doesnt has a classname attribute and the website is a private one for my school, so i cant provide it im afraid

Answer (score 0):

maybe element gets rendered after you scrape the page. have you tried delaying your scraping process to see if it works?

Comment: i delayed it by 4 seconds and also tried 10 and the element definitely loads but it doesnt work

Comment: I believe something is wrong in your xpath, try getting elements one by one from html down to select to see where it stops.
i think you need to have bunch of index in your xpath (like td[0], .etc)

Comment: i now saw that there is a iframe. I switched to it and tried to select the element, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Given the html:

[image: html]

To identify the [select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996687/7429447) element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  drpdClass = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.selectbox[name='element'][onchange^='doDisplayTimetable']"))))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  drpdClass = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='selectbox' and @name='element'][starts-with(@onchange, 'doDisplayTimetable')]"))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```