# Selecting an option from a dropdown using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I want to select the visible text 'planned works' from the following drop-down list HTML:

```
<select id="NewEnquiry.Purpose" data-bind="options: SelectablePurposes, value: Purpose, optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', validationOptions: { rule: 'Enquiry.Purpose' }"><option value="">-- Please Select --</option><option value="">Planned Works</option><option value="">Initial Enquiry</option><option value="">Emergency</option></select>
<option value>-- Please Select --</option>
<option value>Planned Works</option>
<option value>Initial Enquiry</option>
<option value>Emergency</option>
```

The code I have been using, hasn't been working:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('//*[@id="NewEnquiry.Purpose"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text('Planned Works')
```

and using the following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you seeing any error?

Comment: What is the url you are trying to scrape?

Comment: When I run the module I get the following: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: https://onecall.linesearchbeforeudig.co.uk/uk-b4-en/WorkBench  - you'll need an account first :(

Comment: But it's free!!

Answer (score 1):

The `<select>` element seems to be a dynamic element. So to select the `<option>` with text as **Planned Works** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select[id^='NewEnquiry'][data-bind*='SelectablePurposes']")))).select_by_visible_text('Planned Works')
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[starts-with(@id, 'NewEnquiry') and contains(@data-bind,'SelectablePurposes')]")))).select_by_visible_text('Planned Works')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)