# How to select a option from a html select dropdown without any ID attribute using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I am trying to select a value from a dropdown menu using the Selenium Select method but I am unable to correctly locate the right element as illustrated in other Stackoverflow posts as my element lacks an ID as in other Stackoverflow posts. I have tried using the Xpath, Class_Name and CSS_Selector as an alternative but I keep getting an error "Unable to locate element".

This is the HTML:

```
<select class="lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin" data-bind="options: activiteitenOptions, value: activiteit, optionsText: 'Naam', optionsValue: 'Id', visible: toonActiviteiten()" style=""><option value="0bdae2c9-6ebc-4396-b3bb-0e587f9bbe86">Latin Jam</option><option value="c18aef82-be4d-4881-ae96-28aa72161c17">Kiddo Swing 6-8 jr</option><option value="8cbe6618-68cd-47f1-8a79-29db71498292">Ballet </option><option value="8d03eb2f-02ea-434d-8520-30b2f02e18f1">Pilates</option><option value="30358ec5-9751-4b13-8514-4db7b541c540">Gold 40+</option><option value="b811c4be-703b-4193-8f60-57bdb574a60a">Feminine</option><option value="2c6b4f41-6953-4347-99b9-70c33f48da07">City Jam</option><option value="696ba3a2-a453-4550-9cbe-7a00d46dfb14">Dojo</option><option value="fc8b9e43-401f-4e38-8d0b-8afba5f1226b">Power Jam</option><option value="7192a0d5-65b1-43a0-80d6-987b90cf505c">Dans Mix 9 - 12 jr</option><option value="820cf6c6-c9a6-4759-939e-988c646a69f7">Barre Workout</option><option value="e9bfd01d-b183-483a-b809-b2d9dd62354d">Latin House 18+</option><option value="505e1c62-9e68-4569-a7ef-b6566ff1b56d">Afro</option><option value="e4899faa-969e-4953-af1f-bc7eba080bec">Hip Hop</option><option value="796f9e98-f54c-486c-bc62-e6a2e74a5f45">Contemporary Flow </option><option value="88845fb5-e1ab-418d-ba3c-ed1131821835">Modern</option><option value="cb7fa275-b034-4f04-8265-ef747fe73179">Dancehall</option></select>
```

The code of my try at using the `Select()` to change the value is as follows:

```
url = "https://prd.mylogifit.com/logifitweb/genericwidgetbyid.html?a=Touchee&widgetId=73f1f696-5063-4fb7-9a8d-c588ef149eb4"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
browser.get(url)

# Select lesson type (afro)
lesson_droplist = Select(browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin'))
lesson_droplist.select_by_value("Afro")
```

How do I use the Select method to change the drop-down value from Hip-Hop to Afro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the `<option>` with text as **Pilates** as the desired element is a ***dynamic*** element, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://prd.mylogifit.com/logifitweb/genericwidgetbyid.html?a=Touchee&widgetId=73f1f696-5063-4fb7-9a8d-c588ef149eb4")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select.lf-simpelselect.lf-bottom-margin[data-bind*='activiteitenOptions']")))).select_by_visible_text('Pilates')
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://prd.mylogifit.com/logifitweb/genericwidgetbyid.html?a=Touchee&widgetId=73f1f696-5063-4fb7-9a8d-c588ef149eb4")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin' and contains(@data-bind, 'activiteitenOptions')]")))).select_by_visible_text('Pilates')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Pilates]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)

Comment: This code works, thank you so much! How did you know that you had to induce a WebDriverWait based on the HTML of the website? Based on the ' manual process'  I wouldn't have know.

Comment: @MxGr20 Updated the answer with a better phrase and you can find all the reference link embedded within the buzz words. For more help and information we can discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: the apprach doesn't work for the other dropdown and text fields. Eg: 'Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin' and contains(@data-bind, 'activiteitenOptions')]")))).select_by_visible_text('Donderdag 09 Februari ...')
' doesn't select the right <option>. Same for WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='lf-textbox lf-bottom-margin' and contains(@data-bind, 'voornaam')]"))).click().send_keys('MxGr20') doesn't input right text.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

lesson_droplist = Select(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lf-simpelselect"))
lesson_droplist.select_by_visible_text("Afro")
```

You should select by **visible text** *not* value

---

If you want to select by value then

```
lesson_droplist= Select(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "lf-simpelselect"))
lesson_droplist.select_by_value("505e1c62-9e68-4569-a7ef-b6566ff1b56d") #Afro's value
```

Comment: Hi xFranko, thank you for your reply! My problems is with selecting the element as my code and your code (using By.Class_Name) gives the error: NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".lf-simpelselect"}

This confuses me as the mehod we use should be able to locate the element

Comment: @MxGr20 try adding some delay to wait until the element appears, maybe take a look at undetected Selenium 's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The Class name has more than one matches, that is why you are getting that error, try the below XPath:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//select[@class='lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin'])[2]"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Afro")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought the same but when I copy and paste your code I still get the same error.

Comment: I executed this code, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath with some solution for waiting. There are two option time library or WebDriverWait.

You can try this one for time libray:

```
import time

time.sleep(3)
dropdown = Select(browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "(.//select[@class='lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin'])[2]"))
dropdown.select_by_visible_text("Afro")
time.sleep(3)
text = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-bind='text: lesOmschrijving()']").text
print(text)
```

You can try this for WebDriverWait(but its just wait for this XPath and you might be need another waiting for getting another text):

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(.//select[@class='lf-simpelselect lf-bottom-margin'])[2]")))
```

Generally, you need an wait to make sure the relevant elements are loaded in the browser.