# Selenium Driver Web Scraping is unable to get the drop-down element when multiple windows open

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am web scraping a URL https://ephtracking.cdc.gov/DataExplorer/ using the below code

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.headless = False

options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors') 

driver = Chrome(options=options, service=chrome_service) 

driver.get(url)
wait= WebDriverWait(driver,20)

step1Content_click = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((
      By.XPATH,'//select[@id="contentArea"]//option[text()="Tornadoes"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", step1Content_click)
```

However, it's unable to select the option `Tornadoes` from the drop-down list of the `Step1 Content` -> `Select Content Area`.

Answer (score 0):

To select the [select-options](/questions/tagged/select-options) with text ***Tornadoes*** from the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ephtracking.cdc.gov/DataExplorer/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#contentArea[data-qp-data-name='contentAreas']"))).click()
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#contentArea[data-qp-data-name='contentAreas']")))).select_by_visible_text("Tornadoes")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://ephtracking.cdc.gov/DataExplorer/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='contentArea' and @data-qp-data-name='contentAreas']"))).click()
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='contentArea' and @data-qp-data-name='contentAreas']")))).select_by_value('39')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: Tornadoes]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to select an option from the dropdown menu using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094428/how-to-select-an-option-from-the-dropdown-menu-using-selenium-and-python/62094641#62094641)

Answer (score 0):

Check the working code below:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://ephtracking.cdc.gov/DataExplorer/")
wait= WebDriverWait(driver,60)
select = Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "contentArea"))))
select.select_by_visible_text("Tornadoes")
time.sleep(30)
```

**Result:**

[image]